# How to import a public key in python with Crypto?

Tags: python

In python I am trying to import a public key as follows (omitting a lot of characters):

```
public = "MIGfMA0G...."
RSA.importKey(public)
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

How to create a RSA object with the public key when I have the key in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to import the key, if it has the header, is imported correctly:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCS{...}QVAwwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
RSA.importKey(key)
```

So the only thing you need is to place the beginning and the end.